# How do I return back to my home screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

So one day I had opened my Iview Maximus 2 laptop and I saw it said, UEFI Interactive Shell v2.1
It also said below it,
EDK I I
UEFI v2.40 (INSYDE Corp. , 0x54420052]
ERROR. No mapping found
Press ESC in 1 seconds to skip startup.nsh or any key to continue.
Shell>

The first time this happened I restarted my laptop and it worked. It happened another time after that and it worked. It took m3 back to my home screen, but now 8 am restarting it multiple times and it is not working. I don’t know what to do. Please help.

I’m also sorry I picked a random tag

Answer (score 0):

Are you booting from USB? Switch USB ports. It is also possible that some BIOS menu features were enabled that should be disabled. Less likely a feature should be enabled that isn't. I recommend restoring factory default in your BIOS/EFI setting menu. If that doesn't resolve the issue, It is possible that you have a failed piece of hardware...anything from a dead switch in a LSI to a EM damaged component on the MotherBoard. But, before you go crazy with it...If this is a computer with another port for your boot hard drive, you could try switching that port too...

This is  a fairly common occurance, and it seems that one answer does not remedy for everyone experiencing this.